# Is my understanding of dX accurate?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, matrix-calculus, differential-forms

When writing $df$, for a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$, I know rigorously speaking, it is a one form, such that $df(p)(v_{p}) = Df(p)(v)$, where $Df(p)$ is the linear transformation for the derivative, and $Df(p) \in \Lambda^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$  ( $\Lambda^{i}(V)$ , means the alternating i tensors on V. $dx^{i}$ then denotes $d\pi^{i}$, where $\pi^{i}$ is the projection map to the ith entry.)

Now in matrix calculus, people write dg, where $g:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is this essentially just the column vector such that ith entry is $dg^{i}$? Now, for $k:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is dk just the matrix where i,j th entry is $dk^{i,j}, \text{the projection to the i,j th entry}$, where $k^{i,j}: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$? Is my interpretation correct?

My understanding of differential forms is quite elementary, basically from reading *Calculus on Manifolds*, if this interpretation is correct, I also wonder does there exist a coordinate-free version, or in general, for a function $f:V \to W$, does $df$ make sense?

Thank you for helping!

Edit: The comments seem to suggest that I can think about df as just Df, but I still wonder, is my interpretation equivalent to the definition of vector-valued 1 forms in this case? Though no coordinates are nice theoretically, thinking $df, f:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as a matrix is easier to work with.

In fact, in one source I'm reading the author defined $df (f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R})$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial X_{ij} }dX_{ij} = tr\left( \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial X }^{\top} dX\right)$, I don't how $dX_{ij}$ would make sense then

Comment: I think the author would need to specify what they mean by $dg$ when $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Did they not explain their notation?

Comment: @littleO not a single matrix calculus source I know talks anything about differential forms, so they typically just write dX, or something like d(AXB) without explaining rigorously what it means. Like typically I think the definition of dg for general g involves some dx, where x is vectorish thing. I guess x should really be the identity map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If you have a link to the matrix calculus reference you’re looking at, I’d be curious to see it.

Comment: @littleO Like maybe [this one](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119541219). I mean this is somewhat rigorous, but the theory is just not developed in my opinion, as dx is basically just a placeholder for a vector that can take any value. The definition of dg is well defined somewhat, but quite weird.

Comment: I honestly like my interpretation using forms way better than his definition

Comment: Hmm, I would have guessed that if $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $x$ then $dg(x)$ denotes the derivative of $g$ at $x$, by which I mean the linear transformation that provides the best approximation for $g$ near $x$.

Comment: If $V,W$ are normed vector spaces and $A\subset V$ is open and $f:A\to W$ is (Frechet) differentiable, then for each point $a\in A$, you have the Frechet derivative $Df_a$, which is a linear map $V\to W$. If you really want to, you can ‘transport’ this to the level of tangent spaces to get a linear map $df_a:T_aA\cong T_aV\cong\{a\}\times V\to W$. But since you’re dealing with vector spaces, the base points become a little redundant. The mapping $df$ is then simply the map $a\mapsto df_a$, and it’s also called *a $W$-valued $1$-form on $A$*.

Comment: But yes, sometimes people use a single letter like $x,X$ (or anything else they may fancy) to denote the identity map on a given space (typically an open subset of a vector space, eg $\Bbb{R}^n$ or some matrix space $M_{m\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ or anything else based on context). The reason is because these identity/inclusion maps are restrictions of linear maps so at every point their Frechet derivative is equal to itself.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much for your explanation, could you define $df_a$ a little more explicitly? I'm confused about what the map is. Also does my definition also work in this specific case? I probably need some time and additional learning to understand vectored-valued 1 forms

Comment: For each $a$, there is a linear isomorphism $T_aA\to V$. Compose $Df_a:V\to W$ to get a map $df_a:T_aA\to W$. Now for the exact definition of this isomorphism, you simply go back to your favorite definition of tangent space to a manifold, and specialize to the case of an open subset of a vector space. Regarding vector-valued $1$-form, no you don’t need to know what it is, I just threw that word out there in case you were incurably curious, so that you had something to search. You can simply call $df$ the exterior derivative of $f$, or the first differential of $f$.

Comment: But really, since you’re in the vector space case i would suggest ignoring these details and just focus on understanding the Frechet derivative $Df:A\to\text{Hom}(V,W)$. It just so happens that people denote this map by a variety of symbols, including $Jf$ (for Jacobian), or $df$ or (in physics sometimes) $\delta f$ or even $f’$ etc… (or literally anything reminding you of a derivative).

Comment: Please explain your title. What is $X$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. I'll look back at this in the future. I guess now since I'm just in vector space I'll just treat df for $f: V \to W$, where V and W are vector spaces as Df, and that is just a specific case of the more general definition you stated about treating df as map $a \mapsto df_a$ right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Uhh I don't know about how these notations were used in matrix Calculus and that's why I asked. I guess it is just the identity as peek-a-boo says

Comment: Re your last edit, thinking of the $n^2$ coordinates that determine an $n\times n$ matrix, this is just the usual *total differential* of a function (here a function on the space f matrices).